# Failing to see real value in Composite/Iterator design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, iterator, composite

I have situation which in theory is perhaps perfect fit for composite and iterator design pattern but the problem I have with these patterns is one can't access the underlying data structure which can be a deal breaker.

Sure I can have a shop in a mall in a city in a country and this makes whole-part relationship and if I make composite pattern of it I can run common methods on all objects (for most part) like what time a store/mall opens and closes but in reality we need more than that.

Take for example a simple task of loading such composite structure from an already saved file into a tree control. Now we really don't even which component is what so we can't even determine if a component should be parent, sibling or child in the tree. We essentially have to do some kind of type check to find out which composite pattern is against in the first place. This is particularly true with external iterator.

At first it seemed like these two patterns in combination has a bigger potential but now they seem of little use.

I am trying to find true justification of these two patterns. Where can it be used best other than the simple text book example like `Print()` `cost()` functions. Am I right that the composite has to be typecasted back to fill a tree control to reflect the hierarchy of composite when it is loaded from a file?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need an [*iterator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern), you need a [*visitor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Iterators are for objects that are uniform; your objects are definitely *not* uniform. Moreover, [*composite*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) tends to work better when objects are used in a uniform way. One classic example is expressions that you calculate; another one is geometric figures that you render on screen. Again, your case is a poor fit for the classic composite pattern, because shops and counties do not have too much in common.

Fortunately, visitor fixes it all: define a visitor class that knows what to do with a city, a county, a mall, and a shop. Make each of these classes "visitable", and arrange them in a composite. Now the unifying property of your classes in a composite is that each one can be visited. The leaf classes will call back the visitor, and pass themselves as an argument. The branch classes will first pass themselves, and then pass the visitor to all their components. This would let you traverse the entire hierarchy in a nice and clean way.

```
class County;
class City;
class Mall;
class Shop;

struct ShoppingVisitor {
    virtual void visitCounty(const County& county);
    virtual void visitCity(const City& city);
    virtual void visitMall(const Mall& mall);
    virtual void visitShop(const Shop& shop);
};
struct ShoppingVisitable {
    virtual void accept(ShoppingVisitor& visitor) const;
};
class County : public ShoppingVisitable {
    vector<ShoppingVisitable*> children;
public:
    virtual void accept(ShoppingVisitor& visitor) const {
        visitor.visitCounty(*this);
        for (int i = 0; i != children.size() ; i++) {
            children[i]->accept(visitor);
        }
    }
};
class City : public ShoppingVisitable {
    vector<ShoppingVisitable*> children;
public:
    virtual void accept(ShoppingVisitor& visitor) const {
        visitor.visitCity(*this);
        for (int i = 0; i != children.size() ; i++) {
            children[i]->accept(visitor);
        }
    }
};
struct Mall : public ShoppingVisitable {
    virtual void accept(ShoppingVisitor& visitor) const {
        visitor.visitMall(*this);
    }
};
struct Shop : public ShoppingVisitable {
    virtual void accept(ShoppingVisitor& visitor) const {
        visitor.visitShop(*this);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, so the composite would be that of visitors. I have to refresh my visitor to understand all of it, got to think on it more.

Comment: So if my visitor needs to access private structures in shop/mall etc, it still doesn't have access to it. Also I need to store this whole data (hierarchy) in file which would be better in a (logically) tree like structure. Than I should be able to load all this data from that file as well. I am not sure if the visitor address that issue.

Comment: @zadane Your visitor (or any other class, for that matter) should not have access to private structures of your other classes. If you must grant access to such private structures, declare the corresponding visitor a `friend` of your other classes. You can easily use this for writing out your hierarchies by defining a visitor that walks the hierarchy and writes results into a file. Reading the data back would require a different piece of code, though, because visitor requires classes to be in memory.

Answer (score 0):

An example of an stl compliant external iterator of a composite, see this [composite-iterator](https://github.com/kkruecke/composite-iterator) repository on github. It is a forward iterator. *iter returns the base class, Node. 
The composite is the file system example from Pattern Hatching. See p. 25 of these [slides](http://www.fb9dv.uni-duisburg.de/se/en/education/ws0405/se2/despat.pdf) for the description and class diagrams. Directory is the composite. The leaf nodes are File instances, and the base component class for both is Node. 
Example

```
Directory::iterator iter_current = top.begin();
Directory::iterator iter_end = top.end();

for (;iter_current != iter_end; ++iter_current) {

      Node &node = *iter_current;

      cout << "[address: " << hex << &node << "] " << node.getName();

      if (dynamic_cast<Directory*>(&node) ) {

            cout << " is a Directory ";
      } else {
            cout << " is a File ";
      }
      cout << endl;
}
```